# Could not store data in Redis data storage - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a problem with storing data into Redis storage. Redis is dockerized. I have to mention that connection to Redis is successfully opened and querying data works perfectly fine - there is no issues at all but when I'm trying to store data the exception bellow occurs.

> Exception:

```
org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.UncategorizedKeyValueException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(KeyValuePersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.resolveExceptionIfPossible(KeyValueTemplate.java:484)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:379)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.update(KeyValueTemplate.java:209)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.save(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

> Model:

```
@RedisHash("TaskSubscriber")
public class TaskSubscriber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20190329202800L;

    private String id;
    private String destination;
    private String username;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public TaskSubscriber() { }

    public TaskSubscriber(String sessionId, String destination, String username)
    {
        this.id = sessionId;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

> Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskSubscriberRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskSubscriber, String> {

    List<TaskSubscriber> findAllByDestination(String destination);

    List<TaskSubscriber> findAllByUsername(String username);
}
```

In service class I'm just calling **save** method from TaskSubscriber repository passing TaskSubscriber model with data.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the exception have a root cause(s). That one looks like it might be lacking data.

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IS923

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Spring Boot - 1.4.0.RELEASE Redis-Client: 2.9.0 spring-boot-starter-data-redis: 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4.0 but Redis Starter 2.0.6? I would think both of those should be the same version, no?

Comment: I will try with that version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190941/discussion-between-not-a-jd-and-heril-muratovic).

Comment: same error occurred.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic , can you please share your redis configuration and redis logs when this exception comes.

Comment: I have tried with RedisTemplate instead of RedisRepository and everything works fine.